# Get Names from a DataBase and use them in a choiceBox with java

Tags: java, mysql, database, javafx, scenebuilder

I'm Struggling with getting the Values of a Column called 'Names' in my Database. I also need them to be insered into an `Observabllelist` so I can use them as options in a `choiceBox`.

```
@FXML
        ObservableList GetTournamentsName() throws SQLException {

            ObservableList<String> optionList = null;

            Connection con = DBconnection.getConnection();
            Statement st = con.createStatement();
            String sql = ("SELECT Name FROM `tournaments`");
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);

            if (rs.next()) {
                optionList =  FXCollections.observableArrayList(rs.getString("Name"));
                con.close();
            }
            return optionList;
        }
```

and then I initialize the scene of my application by assigning to the `Choicbox TournamentsOption` the Values that I get from the `GetTournamentsName()` method.

```
@FXML
     void initialize() throws SQLException {
        TournamentsOption.setItems(GetTournamentsName());
     }
```

The code Works just partially, I infact get the first Name in the Table but not all the other ones. So that is what I am asking about, how do I get ALL the values?
Thank you in advance for all the help!

Comment: optionList =  FXCollections.observableArrayList(rs.getString("Name")); What is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare and initialize your optionList first. Then you add the data to it. Your approach will only ever have one data String in it. You also closed your connection in the wrong place.

```
   @FXML
    ObservableList GetTournamentsName() throws SQLException {

        ObservableList<String> optionList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

        Connection con = DBconnection.getConnection();
        Statement st = con.createStatement();
        String sql = ("SELECT Name FROM `tournaments`");
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);

        while(rs.next()) {
            optionList.add(rs.getString("Name")));

        }

        con.close();
        return optionList;
    }
```

Comment: Thank You a Lot Sedrick! It works perfectly, now the solution seems so obvious, hahaha !!

Answer (score 2):

In here you have a  `if (rs.next()) {` it will not iterate for `rs.next()`
You need to make it `while (rs.next()) {` and changed the adding logic as required